# What are the remaining cases to consider for this problem, specifically all the possible premises for $i(q)$?

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$. (Note that the divisor sum $\sigma$ is a [multiplicative function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function).)

A number $P$ is said to be *perfect* if $\sigma(P)=2P$.  If a perfect number $N$ is *odd*, then $N$ is called an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers).  Euler proved that a hypothetical odd perfect number $N$ must have the form
$$N = q^k n^2$$
where $q$ is the special prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

It is known that
$$i(q)=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))=\frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2}=\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k},$$
where $i(q)=\sigma(N/{q^k})/{q^k}$ is the index of $N$ at the (special) prime $q$, as initially defined by [Broughan, Delbourgo, and Zhou](https://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/n39/n39.pdf), and whose results were eventually improved upon by [Chen and Chen](https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/colloquium-mathematicum/all/136/1/88031/on-the-index-of-an-odd-perfect-number).

In a recent [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.08116), Dris proves that the following implication holds:
$$i(q) \text{ is squarefree } \implies \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2} \text{ is not squarefree.}$$
We likewise obtain the biconditional
$$i(q) \text{ is a square } \iff \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2} \text{ is a square.}$$
This implies that we have the chain of implications
$$i(q) \text{ is a square } \implies \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2} \text{ is a square } \implies \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2} \text{ is not squarefree.}$$

These findings highly suggest that $\sigma(q^k)/2$ is **not squarefree**.

My question is as follows:

> What are the remaining cases to consider for this problem, specifically **all the possible premises** for $i(q)$?

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and attention!  Therefore, the remaining case is when $G = \gcd\bigg(\sigma(q^k)/2, \sigma(n^2)/q^k\bigg) = \gcd(F, H)$ is **squarefree**.  Do you concur, @mathlove!  =)

Comment: Anyway, please do flesh out your [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4386812/what-are-the-remaining-cases-to-consider-for-this-problem-specifically-all-the?noredirect=1#comment9172455_4386812) as an actual answer, so that I can upvote.  Thanks again!  =)

Comment: $G \times J^2 = H$, @mathlove.  (Remark 2.1, page 3 of the [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.08116).)

Comment: In this question, $H = i(q)$.

Comment: So, applying [the logic in your answer below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4387316/28816), since $H$ is an integer, then: (1) $J = 1$ if and only if $H$is squarefree. (2) $G = 1$ if and only if $H$ is a square. (3) The remaining case is when $G > 1$ and $J > 1$.  This case occurs exactly when $G$ is squarefree.

Comment: @mathlove:  Hmmm, from naive logic, **under the assumption that $G$ is squarefree**, I am only getting (from the equation $H = G \times {J^2}$) that: (1) $J=1$ if and only if $H$ is squarefree. (2) $G=1$ if and only if $H$ is a square.  (3) The remaining case is indeed when $G > 1$ and $J > 1$.  Do you have an unconditional proof for your [claim in this previous comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4386812/what-are-the-remaining-cases-to-consider-for-this-problem-specifically-all-the?noredirect=1#comment9172455_4386812)?

Comment: That is, does the condition **$G$ is squarefree** always hold, since the *unique* representation for $H$ is given by $H = G \times J^2$?  Please advise, @mathlove.

Comment: Do you agree then, that the following conditions hold *under the assumption that $G$ is squarefree*, @mathlove? (1)  $J=1$ if and only if $H$ is squarefree.  (2) $G=1$ if and only if $H$ is a square.  (3) The remaining case is (indeed) when $G > 1$ and $J > 1$.

Comment: Yes, I agree. $\ $

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation, @mathlove!  I will accept your answer by tomorrow morning, as I will have to sleep for now.  =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer#Square-free_factors_of_integers) says that "Any arbitrary positive integer $n$ can be represented in a unique way as the product of a square and a square-free integer: $n=m^{2}k$. In this factorization, $m$ is the largest divisor of $n$ such that $m^2$ is a divisor of $n$". Using this, one can say that $m=1$ if and only if $n$ is squarefree, and that $k=1$ if and only if $n$ is a square. Therefore, the remaining case is when $m\gt 1$ and $k\gt 1$.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this self-answer, mainly for my own benefit.

---

I searched for

> "A number is either squarefree, a square, or"

in Google, and one of the results that it returned was this [Math 446 - Homework #3 PDF file](https://www.calstatela.edu/sites/default/files/users/u2536/MATH-4460/hw3.pdf).

I quote the relevant part of that file (**8 (c)**) here:

> > Let $m \geqslant 2$ be an integer.  Then either $m$ is squarefree, or $m$ is a square, or $$m = a\cdot{b},$$ where $a$ is squarefree, and $b$ is a square.