# What conditions on $X$ will guarantee that $\gcd(\text{square part of } X,\text{squarefree part of } X)=1$, if $X$ is neither a square nor squarefree?

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

The following query is an offshoot of this [answer to a closely related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4397033/28816).

---

Denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$.

The topic of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) likely needs no introduction.

Euler proved that a *hypothetical odd perfect number* (which is an **odd** $N$ satisfying $\sigma(N)=2N$), if one exists, must necessarily have the form
$$N = p^k m^2$$
where $p$ is the *special prime* satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

---

Let us first consider the multiplicative form of
$$M = m^2 - p^k = 2^r t,$$
where $\gcd(2,t)=1$ and $r \geq 2$.

[FredH](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82711) gave an unconditional proof for the assertion that $m^2 - p^k$ is **not a square** in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3122247/28816).  Additionally, note that $m^2 - p^k$ is **not squarefree** (basically because $4 \mid (m^2 - p^k)$).  It follows (from mathlove's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4397033/28816)) that, $2^r$ is a square (and therefore, $r$ is even) **if and only if** $\gcd(\text{square part of } M,\text{squarefree part of } M)=1$.

**For posterity's sake, I reproduce mathlove's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4397033/28816) below:**

---

> This is not a direct answer to the question, but I merely wanted to point out that there is an error in your proof that $r$ is even and $t$ is squarefree.

> You have $m^2 - p^k = 2^r t$ where $\gcd(2,t)=1$ and $r \geqslant 2$, and you know that $m^2 - p^k$ is neither a square nor squarefree. Then, you used the fact that if $2^rt$ is neither a square nor squarefree, then $2^rt$ can be represented as the product of a square larger than $1$ and a squarefree integer larger than $1$. The fact itself is correct. Using the fact, it seems that you thought that there are only two possibilities $(2^r,t)=(\text{square},\text{squarefree}),(\text{squarefree},\text{square})$ from which you concluded that $r$ is even and $t$ is squarefree.

> You are missing the other possibilities. For example, you are missing the following cases :

- $(2^{r-1},2t)=(\text{square},\text{squarefree})$ where $r$ is odd and $t$ is squarefree.
- $(2^{r-2},2^2t)=(\text{squarefree},\text{square})$ where $r=3$ and $t$ is a square.

> More importantly, if you want to represent $2^rt$ as $(\text{square})\times (\text{squarefree})$, then I think that you need to know how to represent $t$ as $(\text{square})\times (\text{squarefree})$ including the cases where $t$ is either a square or squarefree. I'll write all the possibilities in the following :

- If $r$ is even and $t$ is squarefree, then $2^rt$ can be represented as $\underbrace{2^r}_{\text{square}}\times \underbrace{t}_{\text{squarefree}}$.
- If $r$ is odd and $t$ is squarefree, then $2^rt$ can be represented as $\underbrace{2^{r-1}}_{\text{square}}\times \underbrace{2t}_{\text{squarefree}}$.
- If $r$ is odd and $t$ is a square, then $2^rt$ can be represented as $\underbrace{2^{r-1}t}_{\text{square}}\times \underbrace{2}_{\text{squarefree}}$.
- If $r$ is even and $t=PQ^2$ is neither squarefree nor a square where $P$ is squarefree, then $2^rt$ can be represented as $\underbrace{2^rQ^2}_{\text{square}}\times \underbrace{P}_{\text{squarefree}}$.
- If $r$ is odd and $t=PQ^2$ is neither squarefree nor a square where $P$ is squarefree, then $2^rt$ can be represented as $\underbrace{2^{r-1}Q^2}_{\text{square}}\times \underbrace{2P}_{\text{squarefree}}$.

> The possibility that we can represent $2^rt$ as $\underbrace{2^r}_{\text{square}}\times \underbrace{t}_{\text{squarefree}}$ is just one of these possibilities. How to represent $2^rt$ as $(\text{square})\times (\text{squarefree})$ depends on how to represent $t$ as $(\text{square})\times (\text{squarefree})$.

---

Here is my:

**QUESTION**

> What conditions on $X$ will guarantee that $\gcd(\text{square part of } X,\text{squarefree part of } X)=1$, if $X$ is neither a square nor squarefree?  (Note that $X$ may not be $M$.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135963/discussion-on-question-by-jose-arnaldo-bebita-dris-what-conditions-on-x-will-g).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the prime decomposition of $X = p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2} \cdots$. If $X$ is not a square *and* not squarefree, this means that among the exponents in the decomposition, there must be at least one $a_i \ge 2$ and at least one odd $a_i$.

The square portion of $X$ must have, for each $p_i$, an exponent with the largest even number $\le a_i$. The squarefree portion, of course, must have each exponent as $1$, though it won't include prime factors with even exponents.

These portions are coprime iff no prime factor occurs in both portions. Any odd exponent $a_i > 2$ necessarily causes both portions to have a factor in common, as $p_i$ will go to the squarefree portion, and $p_i^{a_i-1}$ will be in the square portion. Therefore if the squarefree portion is $q$, then

$$X = k^2q \land (k^2, q)=1 \iff \not\exists p: p^{2i+1} \mid X, i \geq 1$$

This doesn't say much about the rest of the background, but I think this is an answer for $X$ in general.

Examples: $X=360=2^3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5 =36 \cdot 10$. The squarefree portion carries a $2$ because the exponent on $2$ was $3$.

On the other hand, for $X=720$, the extra $2$ falls into the square portion. Leaving $720 = 144 \cdot 5$, leaving the two portions coprime.

Comment: In simple terms, $X$ must have one prime factor with an even exponent, at least one prime factor with an odd exponent, and every odd exponent $=1$.

Comment: *At least* one factor with an even exponent.

Comment: Right. I didn't express myself precisely.