# If $a\ge 1$ and $k = (2a-1)q+2a-2 $ then $k\ge q$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

As is an offshoot of [this earlier MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4648079) I seek to prove that  if $a\ge 1$ and $k = (2a-1)q+2a-2 $ then $k\ge q$

**MY ATTEMPT**

Suppose to the contrary that both
$$k=(2a-1)q+2a-2, a \geq 1$$
and
$$k=1$$
hold.

Then we obtain
$$1=(2a-1)q+2a-2$$
$$3-2a=(2a-1)q$$
$$q = \frac{3-2a}{2a-1}.$$

Let
$$f(a) = \frac{3-2a}{2a-1}.$$
Differentiating $f$ with respect to $a$, we obtain
$$f'(a) = -\frac{4}{(2a-1)^2} < 0$$
which means that $f$ is a *decreasing function* of $a$.  Since $a \geq 1$, then we obtain
$$f(a) \leq f(1) = \frac{3-2(1)}{2(1)-1} = 1.$$

This implies that
$$q = \frac{3-2a}{2a-1} \leq 1.$$
But since $q$ is the special prime, satisfying $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then we have $q \geq 5$.  This is a contradiction.

This proves that the condition $k=1$ is *incompatible* with the assumption "$k=(2a-1)q+2a-2$ with $a \geq 1$".

Here is my:

> **FINAL QUESTION:** As I find my proof in the **MY ATTEMPT** section unsatisfying, can you think of an alternative proof for the same fact?

Comment: Since $2a-1\geqslant 1$ and $2a-2\geqslant 0$, we have $k=(2a-1)q+2a-2\geqslant 1\times q+0=q$.

Comment: By golly, that is by far the simplest proof, @mathlove!  Please write that out as an actual answer so that I may upvote and then accept.  =)

Comment: Rewrite $k = (2a-1)q+2a-2$ as $k = q + 2(a-1)(q+1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $2a−1\geqslant 1$ and $2a−2\geqslant 0$, we have $$k=(2a−1)q+2a−2\geqslant 1\times q+0=q$$

---

Another way :

Since $k$ is a function of $a$, writing $k$ as
$$k=(2q+2)a-q-2$$
we get
$$k=(\underbrace{2q+2}_{\text{positive}})a-q-2\geqslant (2q+2)\times 1-q-2=q$$

Answer (score -1):

Here is an *alternative (and direct) proof*.

---

Suppose that $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$ satisfying $k=(2a-1)q+2a-2$ with $a \geq 1$.

We want to show that $k \neq 1$.  (In other words, we wish to show that $k > 1$, and therefore that $k \geq 5$, since $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ ought to hold for positive $k$.)

Since $k=(2a-1)q+2a-2$ with $a \geq 1$ by assumption, we derive
$$k+1=(2a-1)q+(2a-1)=(2a-1)(q+1).$$

Since $a \geq 1$ is an integer, then $2a-1 \geq 1$ holds, so that
$$(q+1) \mid (k+1).$$

This last divisibility constraint implies that
$$q + 1 \leq k + 1$$
from which we infer that
$$q \leq k.$$

However, since $q$ is the special prime, satisfying $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then we know that $5 \leq q$ holds.

We therefore conclude that
$$5 \leq q \leq k,$$
or, by transitivity,
$$5 \leq k.$$

**QED**